# Codeigniter: PHP error on all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I have been working on a site using codeigniter. On localhost, everything works well but when I uploaded it online, all its pages got a php error below the footer. The error is as shown below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0
```

**The Controller**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
  $this->load->library(array('session'));
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->model('property_model');
 }
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = "iRent-Home";
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
}
}
```

I thought the error might be caused by the header or footer views since they are loaded on each page. I have counter checked the code in those two views and they look okay. I think it might also be a permissions issue, tried giving several files permission but it didn't work. Anyone with an idea what the problem is?

Comment: No, but in this case, you need to debug line by line. Let's add a row, `die('xxx');`. If only xxx appears, that does mean, the error comes later. Move to the next php line. Do it again while you find where is the problem.

Comment: Or setup your own error handler.

Comment: Thanks lolka_bolka , I will try doing that. Hope it works

Comment: Post your controller, then it's easy to figure out.

Comment: Hi, still looking for a solution for this problem. I have tried applying what lolka_bolka suggested yet there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

kindly read the documentation on errors https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html and review your code

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I have gone through that documentation tried changing the environment from 'development' to 'production', but the error still persists